# Jenkins Swap Space on Slave server - Killed processes to get RAM back but SWAP is not free, How safe is swapoff -a

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, free, swap

```
$ uname -a
Linux some-linux-prod-server-123 3.19.0-51-generic #58~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 26 22:02:58 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I read couple of blogs here on stackoverflow / other sites about how safe is it to run `swapoff -a` and what are the dangers of running it while your Available Free RAM (free + cached as per my understanding) is lower than total SWAP space. I get that, but I'm having the following issue.

**Issue:**
On Jenkins slave server, there are couple of Docker slave processes which are running and eats most of the RAM. In my case, the Docker slaves are persistent i.e. they are **NOT** use-throw model / ephemeral (i.e. **not using** *Docker once retention policy* as per `Docker Plugin` available for Jenkins). We need those slaves to be up and running most of the time where the jobs run every minute (`* * * * *`), yea I know.

Running the following command shows the top 10 of such memory consuming processes.

```
$ ps -eo pmem,pcpu,vsize,pid,cmd | sort -k 1 -nr | head
```

If I want to free up some space, I have written a Groovy (Scriptler) script which periodically (via Jenkins) runs and kills the docker containers running on the slave server (the script is safe i.e. it doesn't kill the container until a given slave is idle). That does free up the RAM and I get almost all of my slave server's RAM back.

Total RAM is `24GB`, while there are bunch of docker container based slave processes are in running state (each Docker slave is set in Jenkins global configurations to start with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms2G -Xmx4G` JAVA Option settings), I mostly see Free RAM is somewhere between 2-6GB free.

Sometime free RAM goes below a threshold (slave server's vm.swapiness is currently set to 60) and Kernel starts using available SWAP space. **I could change the swapiness to 10** (*recommended*) but **I'm not worried about it for now**.

In my case, the total SWAP space is: `1GB` (and lets assume I don't want to increase it). What I'm noticing is, even after I manually kill the docker based containers/slaves running on the slave server and get my free RAM back to 20-22GB free, the SWAP space is still not getting freed up. **PS:** because the Jenkins jobs run every minute, the next time those jobs are launched to run, they all look for available docker container slaves and Docker Plugin successfully spins them up (takes less than 15 seconds if those slaves were killed manually or via my Groovy script) and run those jobs (which in my case takes only less than 15 seconds to do its work), this whole operation makes the free RAM back to 2-6GB free. Overtime, free RAM goes below a threshold and it starts to use SWAP space upto a point, when low SWAP space alert is fired from the monitoring tool.

**What I'm trying to solve**: Our monitoring tool frequently fires alert emails which shows that on the slave server your SWAP space is only 10-30% free and we should fix it. If we don't then it keeps sending those alerts to larger audience if SWAP free space continuously drops towards 0% free SWAP.

**What I know so far:**

1) Running `swapoff -a` is dangerous / not recommended. Still other blogs say that it's sometime safe if a given condition is met.

2) Even if I kill my docker slaves, I see total free RAM is back to normal but SWAP space (if it was used in past), remains the same i.e. OS is not pushing the data (sitting in SWAP) back to physical memory to free up available free SWAP.

3) If `swapoff / swapon` are valid system administration commands, then why not use them efficiently. My current understanding is, **it is safe to run** `sudo swapoff -a` followed by `sudo swapon -a` **IF** current **RAM** *(free + cached)* is greater than **total SWAP space** + some extra buffer one can take (lets say 1-2GB more). I'm assuming if I take an extra buffer (of 1-2GB free / cached RAM) to my calculation for initiating `sudo swapoff -a`, it will be safer in conditions where I run `sudo swapoff -a` and some heavy process(es) start at the same time consuming the available free RAM and start hitting the SWAP space.

4) If I can use **ephemeral** docker slaves, the issue will not come that often. Like I said above, even after killing the container slaves, SWAP doesn't free up and monitoring tool keeps firing the alert for low SWAP space left.

**What I'm trying to do:**

1) To free up SWAP space and not to get any SWAP alerts. **PS:** I don't want to disable alerts coming from the monitoring tool.

2) I wrote a simple script `free-swap.sh` which currently does the following main steps and uses `free -h` command's output to find some values.

- It finds free RAM
- It finds cached RAM
- Adds these 2 values and treat it as **available memory** (variable `amem`)
- It finds Total SWAP space.
- If (free + cached) RAM is more than > Total SWAP space, then it runs the
  following commands:

`sudo swapoff -a && sleep 2 && sudo swapon -a && sudo swapon -s && echo &&  sleep 2 && free -h`

**I can enhance the IF statement** logic, to also have an additional 1-2GB RAM added to **stot** total swap size variable and finally comparing it with **available memory** *amem* for initiating `sudo swapoff -a` so that if my script launches `sudo swapoff -a` **and just before doing that**, if some other processes are initiated on the machine and it eats up some more RAM, then I'm still good to run `sudo swapoff -a` operation; as running `sudo swapoff -a` when RAM (free + cached) **is close to -or- less than** Total SWAP size (and / or some additional buffer 1-2GB) is considered dangerous on a live machine (especially with older kernel versions).

I'm getting some push back on not to periodically run my script (`free-swap.sh`) but I'm curious to find out, why not run it, if the calculation to initiate `sudo swapoff -a` operation is correct OR can be done safely **and** how to free up SWAP space efficiently (**in my case** where Jenkins jobs are running every minute spinning up new Docker slaves if I do Kill  them; otherwise they persist).

**Here is my script** `free-swap.sh` (**again** I can **enhance** this script by having an additional buffer (of having an extra 1-2GB free RAM added to total swap size variable) in comparing with **available memory** (*free+cached*) with `stot` variable (which currently just contains total swap size) i.e when my IF statement is evaluated for running `sudo swapoff -a`, I make sure I have enough RAM for **swapoff** operation to successfully push data back to physical memory and free up the SWAP space even if at the very last minute if some processes start and eats up more RAM, my swapoff operation will still have enough RAM to succeed. If this script can be enhanced in any other fashion, please advise, what can I add / change in it.

```
#!/bin/bash

## Check for MacOS / Darwin machine, if true, exit out gracefully.
if [[ "$(uname -s)" == "Darwin" ]]; then echo -e "\n\n-- This script won't run on a Mac OS / Darwin machine. Exiting gracefully with exit code: 0.\n\n"; exit 0; fi

## Total swap
stot="$(free -h|grep "^Swap:" | sed "s/[ \t][ \t]*/ /g;s/\([0-9]\)[A-Z]/\1/g" | cut -d' ' -f2)"

## Find free RAM
fmem="$(free -h|grep "^Mem:" | sed "s/[ \t][ \t]*/ /g" | cut -d' ' -f4)";
## Convent free mem to decimals if the value is in MBs
if [[  `echo $fmem | grep [0-9]M$` ]];
then
 fmem="$(echo $fmem|sed "s/M//")";
 fmem="$(echo $fmem / 1000 | bc -l| grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]\{3\}")";
 if [[ $(echo "${fmem} < 1.0" | bc) -eq 1 ]]; then fmem="0${fmem}"; fi
fi
## Convent free mem to decimals if the value is in KBs
if [[  `echo $fmem | grep [0-9]K$` ]];
then
 fmem="$(echo $fmem|sed "s/K//")";
 fmem="$(echo $fmem / 1000000 | bc -l| grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]\{3\}")";
 if [[ $(echo "${fmem} < 1.0" | bc) -eq 1 ]]; then fmem="0${fmem}"; fi
fi
## Convent free mem to decimals if the value is in GBs
if [[  `echo $fmem | grep [0-9]G$` ]];
then
 fmem="$(echo $fmem|sed "s/G//")";
 if [[ $(echo "${fmem} < 1.0" | bc) -eq 1 ]]; then fmem="0${fmem}"; fi
fi

## Find cached RAM
cmem="$(free -h|grep "^Mem:" | sed "s/[ \t][ \t]*/ /g;s/\([0-9]\)[A-Z]/\1/g" | cut -d' ' -f7)";
## Convent cached mem to decimals if the value is in MBs
if [[  `echo $cmem | grep [0-9]M$` ]];
then
 cmem="$(echo $cmem|sed "s/M//")";
 cmem="$(echo $cmem / 1000 | bc -l| grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]\{3\}")";
 if [[ $(echo "${cmem} < 1.0" | bc) -eq 1 ]]; then cmem="0${cmem}"; fi
fi
## Convent cached mem to decimals if the value is in KBs
if [[  `echo $cmem | grep [0-9]K$` ]];
then
 cmem="$(echo $cmem|sed "s/K//")";
 cmem="$(echo $cmem / 1000000 | bc -l| grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]\{3\}")";
 if [[ $(echo "${cmem} < 1.0" | bc) -eq 1 ]]; then cmem="0${cmem}"; fi
fi
## Convent cached mem to decimals if the value is in GBs
if [[  `echo $cmem | grep [0-9]G$` ]];
then
 cmem="$(echo $cmem|sed "s/G//")";
 if [[ $(echo "${cmem} < 1.0" | bc) -eq 1 ]]; then cmem="0${cmem}"; fi
fi

## Add to find actual available RAM
amem="$(echo $fmem + $cmem | bc)"

## Show Swap size details
echo
echo "------------------------------------------"
echo -en "Swap Details:"
free -h|egrep "total|^Swap:" | sed "s/[ \t][ \t]*shared.*//g;s/^[ \t][ \t]*/ /;s/ used/used/"
echo "------------------------------------------"
echo -e "Total Swap space (in GB): $stot";
#echo "------------------------------------------"
echo; echo;

## Show details
echo "------------------------------------------"
echo -e "RAM Details:"
echo "------------------------------------------"
echo -e "Free         RAM (in GB): $fmem";
echo -e "Cached       RAM (in GB): $cmem";
echo "------------------------------------------"
echo -e "Avaialble    RAM (in GB): $amem";
#echo "------------------------------------------"
echo; echo;

## If available RAM memory is > Total Swap, then free SWAP space.
## No need to check if SWAP is already free or not.
## Just do it anyways as this can be a periodic operation running from Jenkins.
## This IF statement logic can be enhanced to add 1-2[MG]B extra RAM for variable stot (total swap size) and compare it with amem (available memory which is sum of free + cached RAM).
if [[ $(echo "${amem} > ${stot}" | bc) -eq 1 ]];
then
  echo -e "\nAvailable RAM (free + cached) is more than total Swap, thus SWAP can be freed without any issues\n...\n";
  sudo swapoff -a 2>/dev/null 1>&2 && sleep 2 && sudo swapon -a 2>/dev/null 1>&2 ; sudo swapon -s 2>/dev/null 1>&2;
  sleep 2;
  echo "------------------------------------------"
  echo -en "Swap Details:"
  free -h|egrep "total|^Swap:" | sed "s/[ \t][ \t]*shared.*//g;s/^[ \t][ \t]*/ /;s/ used/used/"
  echo "------------------------------------------"
  echo; echo;
  free -h
  echo; echo;
fi
```

Comment: On high-RAM systems, you should generally disable swap *permanently*. And yes, it's always safe as long as enough usable RAM exists.

Comment: Thanks @o11c. I wonder if anything can be done to enhance the above script, if I'm not catching it already? Have you come across such script which is tested well on a live machine. It seems like my script will do it but just double checking if someone else have written and tested it on  production servers over time without any issues cropping due to swapoff command.